# Highchart doesn't show series group in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, charts, highcharts

I have made few charts with Highcharts.js.
Everything works fine in Modern browers but IE8.

On IE8 my charts only print axis and labels but not actual series. As the below image.
[image: Please click here to see the image]

After some debugging, I found the following information.
[image: Please click here to see the other image]

Seems like highchart-series-group has "visibility: hidden" attribute. I don't know if it is the issue. I tried to change it to visible, but no luck.

Please help me :'(

Here is one of the drawing-chart function that I made

```
    function drawDeviceAssetProjectionPerMonth() {
      Highcharts.setOptions({
       colors: ['#1abc9c', '#428bca', '#d9534f', '#f0ad4e', '#5bc0de', '#1d2939']
      });
      $('#device-assets-projections-per-month-view').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 230
      },
      title: { text: '' },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['March, 2013', 'April, 2013', 'May, 2013', 'June, 2013', 'July,      2013']
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: { text: '' }
      },
      legend: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        reversed: true
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Concerntrator installation',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
       }, {
        name: 'Direct measured',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
       }, {
        name: 'Troubleshoot measurepoint',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
       },{
        name: 'CT measured',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
}
```

I have 31 charts in the site with respective functions which are look more or less like above function, and all of them just showing axis, not bars or pies.

Comment: Any js code to show for highcharts? How are you generating it?

Comment: Highcharts demos work fine in IE8: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/ They have visibility:hidden too and it doesn't affect the chart. Something is wrong with your code, not with charts.

Comment: Please replicate you exampels as live demo (jsfiddle.net) and supply full revision of your IE8

Comment: I have added the code, please have a look :)

Comment: I run this example http://jsfiddle.net/k57wZ/show in the IE8 and all works fine (http://i57.tinypic.com/jv0k7n.jpg)

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for trying it out :). I figured it has nothing to do with my code. I am running the site with Tomcat. When I make a testchart.html and save it on my desktop, run it without any server in IE8, it works perfectly. But if I copy the exact same file into my Tomcat project folder and run it with localhost, it only shows axis. So I think it has something to do with Tomcat server... ...

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with Highcharts and IE8 And finally find this :

http://www.sysaid.com/Sysforums/posts/list/10663.page

after register vgx.dll every things just work well.
I hope that helps.